# Please clarify the behavior of Reader Monad type

Tags: haskell, monads

I am relatively new to Haskell. Now I am trying to understand the Reader Monad more fully. It seems to be clearer the purpose and usage of it. But in Haskell while viewing the type of `:t reader` function I see `reader :: MonadReader r m => (r -> a) -> m a`. What does this type constraint mean? 
When I am trying to construct Reader, e.g

```
let myR = reader (\x -> x + 10)
```

I see error

```
<interactive>:21:11:
No instance for (MonadReader a0 m0) arising from a use of `reader'
The type variables `m0', `a0' are ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance MonadReader r' m =>
           MonadReader r' (Control.Monad.Trans.Cont.ContT r m)
    -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Reader.Class'
  instance MonadReader r ((->) r)
    -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Reader.Class'
  instance (Control.Monad.Trans.Error.Error e, MonadReader r m) =>
           MonadReader r (Control.Monad.Trans.Error.ErrorT e m)
    -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Reader.Class'
  ...plus 10 others
In the expression: reader (\ x -> x + 10)
In an equation for `myR': myR = reader (\ x -> x + 10)

<interactive>:21:27:
No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of `+'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus three others
In the expression: x + 10
In the first argument of `reader', namely `(\ x -> x + 10)'
In the expression: reader (\ x -> x + 10)
```

It is clear that I should add type signature:

```
let myR = reader (\x -> x + 10) :: Reader Int Int
```

This works but how I could imply from this definition of reader `reader :: MonadReader r m => (r -> a) -> m a` that I should define it as `Reader Int Int`?

(In case of Maybe, e.g. `let m5 = return 5 :: Maybe Int` it seems to be clear for me, probably because of Maybe has one type parameter, I am not sure)

Comment: What is the context? I can write `let myR = (\x -> x + 10)` at the GHCi prompt, with `myR :: (Num a, MonadReader a m) => m a`, and `myR 5` evaluates to 15.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be able to default the `Int` Haskell doesn't default the `Monad` to `Reader`.

```
let myR = reader (\x -> x + 10) :: Num a, MonadReader a m => m a
```

Is roughly what the type checker finds, then it applies a defaulting rule for `Num` to `Int` and gets.

```
let myR = reader (\x -> x + 10) :: MonadReader Int m => m Int
```

However it has no default defined for `MonadReader` so has to return an ambiguous error at this point.

All isn't lost though, you can annotate some other part of the program if you don't want to annotate `myR`, the type checker just eventually needs to be told which `MonadReader` you want.